# how to speed up looping over 4GB tab delimited text file

Tags: python-3.x

It took me over 3 minutes to loop over a 4gb text file, counting the number of lines, number of words and chars per line as I go. Is there a faster way to do this?

This is my code:

```
import time
import csv
import sys
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
i=0
countwords={}
countchars={}
start=time.time()
with open("filename.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t"):
        i+=1
        countwords[i]=len(str(line).split())
        countchars[i]=len(str(line))
        if i%10000==0:
            print(i)
end=time.time()
if i>0:
    print(i)
    print(sum(countwords.values())/i)
    print(sum(countchars.values())/i)
    print(end-start)
```

Comment: (I have an 8th gen I7 and 16gb ram)

Comment: Did you try `append()`ing to a python list, instead of using a dictionary?

Comment: I did better, it was also pretty slow when I just looped over with no dictionary, just counting with i

Comment: Do you need to use `csvreader`?  Can you get away with just using `for line in file:` and `line.split('\t')` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can do that in a loop.

Comment: I got a hint numpy arrays might help here, buy I haven't managed to make that work yet.

Comment: Are there any punctuation chars in the source file? Or just words, tabs and spaces?

Comment: there are all kinds of chars (probably everything possible), also punctuation

Answer (score 1):

From my limited tested (on a unix dictionary) I get only a minor speedup using numpy, but any win is a win.  I'm not sure if using `csvreader` is a good way of parsing out tabbed delimited text, but I have not checked whether this gives a more optimal speed.

```
import time
import numpy

# Holds count of words and letters per line of input
countwords = numpy.array( [] )
countchars = numpy.array( [] )

# Holds total count of words and letters per file
word_sum = 0
char_sum = 0

start = time.time()

file_in = open( "filename.txt", "rt", encoding="utf-8" )
for line in file_in:
    # cleanup the line, split it into fields by TAB character
    line   = line.strip()
    fields = line.split( '\t' )

    # Count the fields, and the letters of each field's content
    field_count = len( fields )
    char_count  = len( line ) - field_count   # don't count the '\t' chars too

    # keep a separate count of the fields and letters by line
    numpy.append( countwords, field_count )
    numpy.append( countchars, char_count )

    # Keep a running total to save summation at the end
    word_sum += field_count
    char_sum += char_count

file_in.close()

end = time.time()

print("Total Words:   %3d"  % ( word_sum ) )
print("Total Letters: %3d"  % ( char_sum ) )
print("Elapsed Time:  %.2f" % ( end-start ) )
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it help if we know the number of lines in the file in advance?

Comment: @lessreg - I played around with pre-sizing the numpy arrays, but it made things slower.  Perhaps with a larger data set it would help, but you will have to experiment, or do more research.

Comment: just ran it. Was dramatically shorter, 110 seconds. Thanks!

Comment: please see my answer for another fast version

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid allocating extra data, and use lists instead of dictionaries:

```
import time
import csv
import sys
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
countwords=0
countchars=0
start=time.time()
with open("filename.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")):
        words = str(line).split() #we allocate just 1 extra string
        wordsLen = len(words)
        countwords += wordsLen
        # for avoiding posible allocation we iterate throug the chars of the words
        # we already have, then we need to add the spaces in between which is 
        # wordsLen - 1
        countchars += len(itertools.chain.from_iterable(words)) + wordsLen - 1)
        if i%10000==0:
            print(i)
end=time.time()
if i>0:
    print(i)
    print(countwords/i)
    print(countchars/i)
    print(end-start)
```

Comment: this solution worked slower than my original code, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to write another version of a speedy code (using an idea I saw in a different thread), but it currently has a disadvantage compared to Kingsley's code using numpy, because it does not save data per line, but only aggregate data. In any case, here it is:

```
import time

start=time.time()
f = open("filename.txt", 'rb')
lines = 0
charcount=0
wordcount=0
#i=10000
buf_size = 1024 * 1024
read_f = f.raw.read

buf = read_f(buf_size)
while buf:
    lines += buf.count(b'\t')
    '''while lines/i>1:
        print(i)
        i+=10000'''
    charcount+=len((buf.strip()))
    wordcount+=len((buf.strip()).split())
    buf = read_f(buf_size)

end=time.time()

print(end-start)
print(lines)
print(charcount/lines)
print(wordcount/lines)
```